# Reassign event handler at runtime

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

I would like to change the delegate attached to a `BackgroundWorker` at runtime. Would something like below work?

```
DoWorkEvenHandler dweh = new DoWorkEventHandler(method1);
backgroundworker.DoWork += dweh;
```

and at some point later change the delegate associated with `DoWork` by reassigning the reference `dweh`:

```
dweh = new DoWorkEventHandler(method2);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you cannot "assign" a delegate to an event handler. Handlers are attached to events by adding them to the invocation list of an underlying delegate that is used internally to represent the event. This is by design!

And no, you cannot change the handler by changing the object pointed to by a reference that was previously used to attach an event handler; in part because **delegates are immutable**, and in part because you would just be changing the reference to point to something else, not really changing the event handler which is what you're trying to accomplish.

In order to *change* the delegate you have to first remove the previous delegate:

```
backgroundworker.DoWork -= dweh;
```

Then assign a new one by adding it as a handler of the event:

```
backgroundworker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(method2);
```

---

**Note**

In most cases you can remove a handler (delegate) from an event using this syntax:

```
backgroundworker.DoWork -= new DoWorkEventHandler(mehtod1);
```

or using an implicit or explicit method group conversion:

```
backgroundworker.DoWork -= (DoWorkEventHandler)mehtod1;  // explicit convertion    
//  -  or  - 
backgroundworker.DoWork -= mehtod1;                      // implicit (more compact)
```

But depending on the situation you may need to maintain a reference to the previous delegate in order to be able to remove it later. For example this would apply to anonymous methods or lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with the proverbial "extra level of indirection". Write a class like this:

```
public sealed class RedirectableDoWorkEventHandler
{
    public RedirectableDoWorkEventHandler(DoWorkEventHandler handler)
    {
        Contract.Requires(handler != null);
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public DoWorkEventHandler Handler
    {
        get
        {
            return _handler;
        }

        set
        {
            Contract.Requires(value != null);
            _handler = value;
        }
    }

    public void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _handler(sender, e);
    }

    private DoWorkEventHandler _handler;
}
```

And then you can use it something like this:

```
public void Setup()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    // ...

    var handler = new RedirectableDoWorkEventHandler(handler1);

    worker.DoWork += handler.DoWork;

    // And then some time later...

    handler.Handler = handler2; // Now DoWork will call handler2.
}

private void handler1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Whatever
}

private void handler2(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Whatever
}
```

But really, what's the point? You might as well just have one simple handler with an `if` to select among the choices. I suppose it could help to encapsulate things in some cases... YMMV.

Comment: Of course, in the same vein, you could solve this with a branch in the method that handles the event..

Comment: Just as you made that comment, I was adding an extra comment to the same effect. So I definitely agree with you. :)